# Hamburger Menu issue - nav menu not disappearing

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I am having an issue getting my hamburger menu to remain and nav menu to disappear. Is anyone able to help?

```css
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
  color: rgb(0);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  /* Smooth transition for hover effects */
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(140, 71, 147);
  /* Change background on hover */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Change text color on hover */
  transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Slightly increase size on hover */
}


/*MOBILE*/

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.2rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <!-- Navigation Links -->
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="whatson.html">Whats on</a>
  <a href="businesses.html">Businesses</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
</nav>
```

I have been trying for hours and cannot understand what's happening. Thanks in advance

I've tried everything I can think of! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Image of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddr3N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:
Take out the `toggle-button` from the `nav` so it is not made invisible when you toggle it to be hidden.
Give the `nav` an `id: nav` and `class: hide` which means that the `nav` will not show on smaller devices like mobiles due to your media query.
Then use JS to toggle the hide class on and off when the user clicks the button.

```js
document.querySelector(".toggle-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("#nav").classList.toggle("hide")
})
```

```css
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
  color: rgb(0);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  /* Smooth transition for hover effects */
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(140, 71, 147);
  /* Change background on hover */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Change text color on hover */
  transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Slightly increase size on hover */
}


/*MOBILE*/

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.2rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="toggle-button">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</a>
<nav id="nav" class="hide">
  <!-- Navigation Links -->
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="whatson.html">Whats on</a>
  <a href="businesses.html">Businesses</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: so can i keep the nav as is? just add the class?

Comment: ok that worked thanks but the background has gone so i am just left with the hamburger bars and no nav bar background

Comment: Post a jsfiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c4s9pmoq/

Comment: Also when i click it is fine but if i were to choose something from the menu, the menu stays and the hamburger disappears why is this please?

Comment: For the first question add these to your media query `.hide { height: 45px; }` and `.hide a { display: none; }`. When I click a menu item, it takes me to another page so that should not be the case unless there is something else. Probably best for another question.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, also the reason that happens as I have only set it up on one page. Tiredness took over. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class `.nav` in your CSS and there is no such class in the HTML. The tag `nav` doesn't have a class.

You would also need to remove the firt `display: none` from within the media query, since you are already hiding the `a` tags in the next line.

So, your media query in your CSS would be:

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px)
{
    .toggle-button
    {
        display:flex;
    }
   
    
    nav a
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```